# Idle time of an application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

how to calculate idle time of an application in mfc.

If an application session has been idle for more than 15 minutes how to re-authenticate
session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the "GetLastInputInfo" API.

```
UINT GetIdleMS()
{
   LASTINPUTINFO li = { 0 };
   li.cbSize        = sizeof(LASTINPUTINFO);
   GetLastInputInfo(&li);
   return GetTickCount() - li.dwTime;
}
```

Comment: hi i am getting this error ,wht will be the reason - error C2065: 'LASTINPUTINFO' : undeclared identifier

Comment: You have to #define _WIN32_WINNT to be >= 0x0500 for LASTINPUTINFO to be declared in winuser.h

Comment: Hi,Inside my app. i want to instantiate this method when ever an event is generated after some idle time .Where i has to declare this ??

Comment: event generated in the sense any user inputs like mouse,button clicks etc.

Comment: The system automatically resets the input time on mouse and keyboard events. So any time you call the "GetIdleMS()" function (above) it always reports the time since the last user input event.